# Is it possible to use External Objects WITHOUT using (and consequently paying for) Salesforce Connect?

Tags: salesforce-connect

I feel like those two things are joined at the hip but just doing a sanity check here.

I know I can write a custom Apex class that can be interacted with to describe schema and fetch records, but this is still done as part of "Salesforce Connect", yes? With the $4,000/mo pricetag?

Comment: short answer is NO. External objects feature is available as a part of Salesforce Connect.

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy Move this to an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is NO.

External objects feature is a part of Salesforce Connect.

Salesforcer Connect feature is available for free in Developer Edition and for extra cost in Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions.  According to [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_define.htm&type=5)

> Salesforce Connect is available in: Developer Edition and for an extra
>   cost in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments this is a paid feature so you need to paid to SF. Yoiu can check with your sales admin they might able to provide exact amount.

[image]

[Define External Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=external_object_define.htm&type=5)